# Pass multiple matplotlib Axes objects from generator function and display them

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create several histograms with pandas inside a generator function, pass them as a list of matplotlib Axes objects to the main function, and display them one by one.

My code is below. The first figure displays OK, but when I try to display the second I get: "ValueError: Axes instance argument was not found in a figure."

What does this error message mean? How do I fix it?

```
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def make_hist(n,input_data,Xcolname,bins):
    curr_num=0
    while curr_num<n:
        afig = input_data[curr_num][Xcolname].hist(bins=bins)
        yield afig
        curr_num=curr_num+1

 def main():    
    filepath = "C:/Users/Drosophila/Desktop/test.txt"
    filepath2="C:/Users/Drosophila/Desktop/test.txt"
    input_data = load_data_from_file([filepath,filepath2],concatenate=False)

    Xcolname = 's5/s6'

    pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'    

    bins=10

    n=2

    figs=list(make_hist(n,input_data,Xcolname,bins))

    plt.sca(figs[0])
    plt.show()

    plt.sca(figs[1])
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing the problem to a histogram generator:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import random

def make_hist(input_data,bins):
    for row in input_data:
        print(row) # micro-testing: do the hists look about right?
        bin_edges, bin_heights, patches = plt.hist(row, bins=bins)
        yield patches


input_data = random((3, 6))

pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'

fig = plt.figure()
for patches in make_hist(input_data, 10):
    plt.show() 
    fig.clf()
```

Your main problem was that running hist doesn't *return* an axis even though it *uses* one.

Also, I think you're using a generator where you don't need one (passing n in seems backwards), though it's hard to tell out of context. Why not loop through your data and plot whenever you have one plotsworth? Or every `n x m` plotsworth, if you want figures with n rows m columns.